# How to skip empty lines in csv file when reading with python script?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a python script in which I want to read a csv file and then import this data into a postgres table. Unfortunately the csv file is quite messy and has many blank lines.

```
arg = {
     'date': date,
     'store_id': row[0].strip(),
     'price': row[1].strip(),
     'description': row[2].strip()
   }

cur.execute(
 """INSERT INTO 
    "Inventory"("date","store_id","price","description")
    select %(date)s, 
    %(store_id)s, 
    %(price)s, 
    %(description)s
          ;""", arg)
```

I want to skip stripping any row that has an empty cell for store_id and description - how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `continue` to skip the rest of the current loop, but keep on looping. See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

```
for line in open(filename):
    row = line[:-1].split(",")
    arg = {'date': date,
           'store_id': row[0].strip(),
           'price': row[1].strip(),
           'description': row[2].strip()}
    if not arg['store_id'] and not arg['description']:
        continue
    # cur.execute bit here...
```

`not` returns false on a length 0 string, which will happen for an empty cell using the parsing above. Of course change the `and` to `or` if that's what your logic prefers.